# grab issue in blender 2.83.1

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I have upgraded from blender 2.79 to  2.83.1, and then I can not grab mesh, only the origin dot is moving but the mesh stay in place. This was working with 2.79 version.

Comment: Most likely the 3D Viewport is not updating, and it can be fixed by updating your video card drivers.